# Why do I have an "Unexpected Token Syntax Error"

Tags: javascript

```
function UserGuess() {           
   var iHumNum = document.getElementById("UserNum").value;

   if (iComNumberComNumber > iHumNum) {
        document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Too Low! Try again.";
        iLives--;
    }               
    else if (iComNumber < iHumNum) {
         document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Too High! Try again.";
         iLives--;
    }
    else (iComNumber == iHumNum) { // ERROR HERE
         document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Correct! Hit restart to play again!";
    }     
}
```

this is my code and through the combination of `Ctrl + Shift + I` it says I have an error where I have written

```
else (iComNumber == iHumNum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra `if`, it should be `else if (iComNumber == iHumNum)`.

Also, I think your first `if` clause contains an error, `iComNumberComNumber` should probably just be `iComNumber`?

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `if` last condition

```
function UserGuess() {
    var iHumNum = document.getElementById("UserNum").value;

    if (iComNumberComNumber > iHumNum) {
        document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Too Low! Try again.";
        iLives--;
    } else if (iComNumber < iHumNum) { 
        document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Too High! Try again.";
        iLives--;
    } else if(iComNumber == iHumNum) { /* <-- fixed if */
        document.getElementById("DisplayHL").innerHTML = "Correct! Hit restart to play again!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's not supposed to be a conditional statement in your `else` statement. You should remove this statement.